# Laravel 4 created_at field cannot be saved when using eloquent creates record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp, eloquent

Runtime version:

PHP 5.3.10

Laravel 4.0

Create table like this:

```
Schema::create('components', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('component', 128);
    $table->string('description', 128);
    $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model definition:

```
class Component extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'components';
}
```

And create a new record:

```
$component = new Component;
$component->component = 'foo';
$component->description = 'foo description';
$component->created_by = 1;
$component->save();
```

Database:

```
+------+------------+------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | component  | description      | created_by    | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------+------------+------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1    | foo        | foo description  | 1             | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2014-07-09 13:11:55 |
+------+------------+------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Result of DB::getQueryLog():

```
insert into `pf_component` (`component`, `description`, `created_by`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values ('foo', 'foo description',  1, '2014-07-09 13:11:55', '2014-07-09 13:11:55') {"bindings":["foo","foo description",1,"2014-07-09 13:11:55","2014-07-09 13:11:55"],"time":4.64,"name":"mysql"}
```

Comment: Do you also have a table called `pf_component`? The model defines the table name as `components`. Why the difference?

Comment: @Kryten I was set the db prefix:`'prefix'    => 'pf_',`

Answer (score 0):

I was try to set PDO options and solved the problem, but I don't know why.

app\config\database.php

```
'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options'    => array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
        )
    ),
)
```